# C++ iterator for vector of struct Compiler Error

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iterator

I created a `struct` type which contains two variables. I use this data type within a `vector`, that is again stored in a `map`, as following:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    Y y;
    A() {};
    A(int _x, Y _y) { x=_x, y=_y; };
};

typedef std::vector<A> LA;
typedef std::map<uint,LA> MB;

MB b;
```

When I try to use an iterator, such as

```
std::vector<LA>::iterator it = b[x].begin();
```

the compiler gives this error:

> error: no viable conversion from '__wrap_iter< A *>' to
>   '__wrap_iter< std::__1::vector < A, std::__1::allocator< A> > *>'
>           std::vector< LA>::iterator it = b[x].begin();
>
> candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter< pointer>') to 'const std::__1::__wrap_iter< std::__1::vector<  A, > std::__1::allocator< A> > *> &' for 1st argument class__wrap_iter
>
> candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'iterator' (aka > '__wrap_iter< pointer>') to 'std::__1::__wrap_iter< std::__1::vector< A, > std::__1::allocator< A> > *> &&' for 1st argument class__wrap_iter
>
> candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if'

What is the reason for this error? Although I tried several things like operator overloading, I could not solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: `LA::iterator it = b[x].begin();`

Comment: @paulsm4: I said this already. In the answer section. Where it belongs!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have a vector of `LA`; you have a vector of `A`. So:

```
std::vector<A>::iterator it = b[x].begin();
```

or:

```
LA::iterator it = b[x].begin();
```

Looks like a simple typo to me?

(Not very surprising given these terrible type names...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works fine! Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

The others here have already answered why the compiler complained.

So I will not repeat that but give an alternative "fix". It'll only work if you can use C++11 syntax in your project/environment.

If so, the iterator can be created as follows:

```
auto it = b[x].begin();
```

This is not as explicit as when specifiying the exact type for `it`, but at least it's less typing. Note that this will only work in C++11 or higher, and you will need to compile with `-std=c++11` in g++. Visual Studio 2013 and higher will understand that syntax out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The part that goes inside the `<>` in a `std::vector<>` is the type of the object that the vector is going to hold, e.g., `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<double>`.  In your case the *type* of object in the vector is `A`.  So you should write

```
std::vector<A>::iterator it = b[x].begin();
```

or using your `typedef`,

```
LA::iterator is = b[x].begin();
```

Comment: You said something, not exactly what I wrote, though.

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear that the OP knows what vectors are, but okay